# Filtering with a non-literal expression

Tags: odata

How do I create a cross property comparison filter with OData.  i.e. something like

/Orders?$filter=OrderDate gt ShippedDate

All of the OData examples only show literals on the right hand side of the filter expression.

Is this possible with OData, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do that.  Here's a query from Netflix comparing the available dates of DVDs and BluRay titles

```
http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$filter=Dvd/AvailableFrom%20gt%20BluRay/AvailableFrom
```

Answer (score 1):

But of course, here is the relevant ABNF, showing that the left and right values are interchangeable, and both can be memberExpr or boolFunctionCallExpr or even a nonbool expression (eg: lowercase(Category/Slug) eq lowercase(substring(ProcuctName,10)).

```
commonExpr                  =   [ WSP ] (
                                    boolCommonExpr / 
                                    methodCallExpr /
                                    parenExpr / 
                                    literalExpr / 
                                    addExpr /
                                    subExpr / 
                                    mulExpr / 
                                    divExpr /
                                    modExpr /  
                                    negateExpr / 
                                    memberExpr / 
                                    firstMemberExpr / 
                                    castExpr / 
                                    functionCallExpr 
                                ) [ WSP ]

ltExpr                      =   commonExpr WSP "lt" WSP commonExpr
```